# Issues with Logical Groovy Operators in Jenkins Pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, logical-operators, jenkins-groovy

I'm having compound if condition in Groovy script for "Active Choice (Uno) Plugin.

For two condition checks it works fine; however fails when I have 3 conditions to check.

Note: Locat, Envir & regio are parameters in this pipeline.

The below works fine.

```
if (Locat.equals("Dub") && Envir.equals("Dev")) {
return["DD1", "DD2", "DD3", "DD4"]
} else if (Locat.equals("Dub") && Envir.equals("Production")) {
return["DP1", "DP2"]
} else {
return ["Select an IP from the drop-down"]
}
```

The below fails when I add the third condition and the plugin fall backs to error message that we specified.

```
if (Locat.equals("Dub") && Envir.equals("Dev") && region.equals("PRD")) {
return["DD1", "DD2", "DD3", "DD4"]
} else if (Locat.equals("Dub") && Envir.equals("Production")) {
return["DP1", "DP2"]
} else {
return ["Select an IP from the drop-down"]
}
```

Also, compound and/or grouping conditions fail for example below.

```
if (Locat.equals("Dub") && (Envir.equals("Dev") || region.equals("PRD"))) {
```

I tried to find how to write compound condition statements for Groovy scripting but did not find any article which shows 3 or more than 3 condition checks in Groovy scripting.

Need help with this.

Comment: what exactly is the error coming ?

Comment: Check if you haven't made a typo. You said: `Note: Locat, Envir & regio are parameters in this pipeline.`. Then you used the `region` variable. Check if the parameter name is correct. Other than that, maybe try using a different parameter name than `region`. Just to check if `region` is not used already by different Jenkins plugin or environment variable. Your Groovy script looks fine.

Comment: exactly there was a typo. copying script from jenkins portal to microsoft word alters the quotes <'>